# Submit PayPal form & Update Database at same time

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

If I use the standard PayPal form for payments can I also update my db at the same time, by changing the code slightly to include the update details?

This is the standard PayPal payment form I want to use - Will change as necessary..

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="payPalForm">

 <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="01 - General Payment to FreelanceSwitch.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
 <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
 <input type="hidden" name="business" value="your@paypalaccount.com">
 <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
 <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://freelanceswitch.com/payment-complete/">

 Item Details:<br /><input name="item_name" type="text" id="item_name"  size="45">
 <br /><br />
 Amount: <br /><input name="amount" type="text" id="amount" size="45">
 <br /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">

 </form>
```

This is my update coding in my page:

```
 $editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
 if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
   $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
 }

 if ((isset($_POST["MM_update"])) && ($_POST["MM_update"] == "form")) {
   $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE db SET payment_page_completed=%s WHERE id=%s",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['payment_page_completed'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['id'], "int"));

   mysql_select_db($database_connAdmin, $connAdmin);
   $Result1 = mysql_query($updateSQL, $connAdmin) or die(mysql_error());

   //$updateGoTo = "confirmation"; WILL NEED TO CHANGE AS NEEDS TO GO TO PAYPAL


   if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
     $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
     $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
   }
   header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));
 }
```

This is my current form

```
 <form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" name="form" class="" id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" readonly="readonly">
 <input type="hidden" name="payment_page_completed" value="yes" readonly="readonly">
 </form>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it in two ways by submitting form to two sides with two submits on one form, one to paypal and other to the page where you can save it in your db.

EDIT 1:

In your form add two submits like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btns" id="submit1" value="Save in DB" onclick="changeWhere('http://yourwebsite.com/savedata.php');" >

<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btns" id="submit2" value="Move to PayPal"
onclick="changeWhere('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');" disabled="true">
```

and in your script add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeWhere(place){

    document.form.action=place;   //use your forms name inplace of form

}

</script>
```

EDIT 2:

using single submit for two form actions

add this in your form:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitTwice(this.form)">
```

and in script add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function submitTwice(form){
 form.action = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
 form.submit();
 form.action = 'savedata.php';
 form.submit();
}
</script>
```

It works for me. :-)

EDIT 3:

savedata.php may include code like;

```
<?php
$item_name   = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_price  = $_POST['item_price'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];

$sql="Insert into sales (name, price, number) values ('$item_name', '$item_price', '$item_number')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks you... What about savedata.php? Do I need that? What's does it look like/contain?

Comment: savedata.php will contain php script to save data which you want into your database. for instance, you can use it for saving itemname, number and price into your database.

Comment: Ok, had a look having problems with the savedata.php bit and db update. Could you show me your savedata.php so I could see how you did??? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An identical question was posed [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum88/5375.htm) and should give you the answers you need. If you need clarification please comment.

To quote that answer, it involves submitting data to your PHP, then using a socket request to send that data to PayPal:

```
function post($host, $path, $data) { 
$http_response = ''; 
$content_length = strlen($data); 
$fp = fsockopen($host, 80); 
fputs($fp, "POST $path HTTP/1.1\r\n"); 
fputs($fp, "Host: $host\r\n"); 
fputs($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"); 
fputs($fp, "Content-Length: $content_length\r\n"); 
fputs($fp, "Connection: close\r\n\r\n"); 
fputs($fp, $data); 
while (!feof($fp)) $http_response .= fgets($fp, 28); 
fclose($fp); 
return $http_response; 
}
$postdata = '?foo=bar'; 
foreach($_POST as $key => $val) $postdata .= '&'.$key.'='.$val;
```

**Important Notes:** I copied that code from the thread I linked, so check it out for more information. Also, this will submit to your PHP. You'll need to redirect the user to that POST request if you want them to actually view the PayPal page.

Moreover, it seems like you might benefit from using PayPal's Instant Payment Notification feature. This essentially calls back a URL of your choosing with all of the payment information. I found [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/using-paypals-instant-payment-notification-with-php/) immensely helpful in learning how to do this in PHP.

Comment: To add to this, I would use the call back feature of paypal. Do you really want to save data in the event the transaction fails? Submit the data, if it goes through successfully via Paypal, THEN save the data to your DB.

Comment: I very much agree with @luckytaxi. The only time where you may want to implement the method you've asked about is if you want to save information on orders, regardless of if they've been cancelled or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, what I did is to do Ajax pausing my submittion and calling my insert.php. My insert.php pretty much the saving to database. I have written the exact steps here. [Save HTML form POST to database before redirecting to PayPal](http://anytch.com/save-html-form-post-to-database-before-redirect-to-paypal/)

```
<script>

 $(function () {

        $('#senrollnow').on('submit', function (e) {

      var form = $(this);

      if(!form.hasClass('pending')) {

          e.preventDefault();

          form.addClass('pending');

          $.ajax({

              type: 'post',

              url: 'insert.php',

              data: $('#senrollnow').serialize(),

              success: function () {

                form.submit();

                 alert('form was submitted'+data);

              }
          });
      }
});

  $('#freeform').on('submit', function (e) {

  //e.preventDefault(); //prevents the form to submit

          alert("Your request has been sent! Please check your email within 12 hours for my feedback. Thank you.");

        });

      });

</script>
```